# Gamemaker - Retain Overlapping with collision

Tags: game-maker

How is the best way to setup collision so that my player will trigger collision logic when colliding with an enemy and so that I can walk through enemies, per se, but Not be able to walk through walls?

I want the player to always be able to move "through" enemies and overlap enemy sprites, but setting my logic in a collision block seems prevent the overlapping. I obviously want the player to still be able to not walk through walls.

I don't know what I can really try at this point...

Comment: Can you show us the collision code? From the looks of it, you're using the collision code for both checking enemies and walls. I think it should be possible to seperate that, to check for collision between just enemies, and collision between walls. But to understand that better, I'll need to see what the current collision code looks like.